# Add SSL to a Dockerzied wordpress container

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, ssl

I have two Docker containers (Wordpress and MySQL) and I installed Apache on the server.

So it looks something like this;
[image]

I am trying to add an SSL certificate to it with **Certbot**.

So far, my Apache configuration file is this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  <Proxy *>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:4567/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4567/
  <Location />
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have added this two lines of code to **wp-config.php**;

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/');
```

When I use `certbot --apache` and choose the domain to add the SSL certificate, the website "brakes"; no CSS, no JS, no images and I can't access to the admin (to try to change http to https using **Search and Replace**);

I tried to change http with https and add `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` to **wp-config.php** but that didn't work;

Do anyone know the perfect way to add an SSL to Dockerized wordpress container?

*PS:* I tried a desperate move to change manually all the http://example.com to https://example.com in all tables in the database. it didn't work and it is a pretty stupid thing to do, but desperate times call for desperate measures.

Comment: Are you sure that your SSL certificate is working correctly at all? After using certbot you need to link the let's encrypt certificate to your apache config.

Comment: Certbot auto linked the certificate and added the configuration to '.conf' file. And I can see the 'connection-is-secure lock' next to the domain name in the browser, but with mixed content problem.

Comment: @AymenFezai So it works after all ? Mixed content means you have resources (images, videos, css, js etc) loaded over http instead of https - so you need to make them load over https instead.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be https, otherwise your assets will load from http resulting in mixed content.

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/);
```

Comment: I have tried that after adding the ssl but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the apache config file from bitnami images, maybe this helps:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName wordpress.example.com
    ServerAlias www.wordpress.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.key"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```